# dialogApi callback not executing in iPad

Tags: office-js

I am developing an Excel add-in where i use dialogApi for authentication.When i call displayDialogAsync, callback function does not execute.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: _height, width: _width}, dialogCallback)

var dialogCallback = function(asyncResult) {  
             if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {

                // In addition to general system errors, there are 3 specific errors for 
                // displayDialogAsync that you can handle individually.
                switch (asyncResult.error.code) {
                    case 12004:
                        jQuery("body").append("Domain is not trusted");
                        break;
                    case 12005:
                        jQuery("body").append("HTTPS is required");
                        break;
                    case 12007:
                        jQuery("body").append("A dialog is already opened.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        jQuery("body").append(asyncResult.error.message);
                        break;
                }
            }else{                  
             jQuery("body").append("Success");

            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);
            }
    }
```

Above code works fine in windows and Mac OS but does not execute callback in case of iPad.
i'm using Excel 1.25(160603)

-Thanks

Comment: We're examining this issue now and looking to provide a fix if it happens to be a bug..

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to the recent Excel version this error should go away.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks :)